# How to use ColorDistance to find a certain number of equidistant colors in CIE LAB colorspace?

Tags: color

I want to get *n* distinct colors (the value of *n* is to be decided dynamically)  from the CIE LAB Color space such that they are perceptually equidistant based on the measurement by *ColorDistance* and cover the whole range (or a wide range) of the color space.

How can I do this?

Comment: Since CIE LAB is supposedly perceptually uniform, this is equivalent to generating equidistant points in $\mathbb R^3$, no? Should they all be pairwise equidistant? Or each one equidistant to the closest one?